# Replacing NA values with a random value picked from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

In my data I have two columns that contain NA values. So I made a new dataframe which has no NA values, I removed the rows which contaied NA values.

What I want is that each time there is an NA value in the original data (called `metadata` here), I want to sample randomly one sample from the new data frame (called `temp`).. (I removed the NAs so there is no risk of picking NA again).

However, my original data is not changing, it stays the same after performing this:

```
temp = metadata %>% drop_na()
for (i in length(metadata$Gender)){
  if (is.na(metadata$Gender[[i]])) {
    metadata$Gender[[i]] = sample(temp$Gender, 1)
  }
  
  if (is.na(metadata$Age[[i]])){
    metadata$Age[[i]] = sample(temp$Age, 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `for` loop declaration, use `1:length()` or `seq_along()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating another object and replacing the NA based on that, we can loop `across` the columns of interest, `replace` the NA elements with the `sample` on non-NA elements and specify the `size` as the count of NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
metadata <- metadata %>%
    mutate(across(c(Gender, Age), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x),
      sample(.x[!is.na(.x)], size = sum(is.na(.x)), replace = FALSE))))
```